# Function returns empty result

Tags: vb6

I am getting empty msgBox when i call the function . Have a look on code as bellow

```
Public Function Custom(ByVal TableName As String, _
    ByVal EmployeeCode As String, ByVal FieldName As String, ByVal DataToCheck As String, _
    Optional ByVal CodeFieldName As String = Empty, Optional ByVal CodeFieldValue As String = Empty) As Boolean

Dim lstrSQL1 As String
Dim lrsTemp1 As ADODB.Recordset

lstrSQL1 = " Select  " & FieldName & "  from  " & TableName & " Where ID_CARD_NO =" & DataToCheck & ""
'MsgBox (lstrSQL1)

If Len(Trim$(CodeFieldName)) <> 0 And Len(Trim$(CodeFieldValue)) <> 0 Then
   lstrSQL1 = lstrSQL1 & " AND " & CodeFieldName & " <> '" & CodeFieldValue & "'"


End If

Set lrsTemp1 = cObjDBConn.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL1)

If lrsTemp1 Is Nothing Then
    Custom = False
ElseIf Not (lrsTemp1.BOF And lrsTemp1.EOF) Then
    Custom = True
ElseIf lrsTemp1.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Custom = False
Else
    Custom = False
End If

If lrsTemp1.State = adStateOpen Then lrsTemp1.Close
Set lrsTemp1 = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrorHandle:

    Custom = False


End Function
```

The calling code is here:

```
If gobjValidation.Custom(fstrTableName, gEmployeeCode, "EMPLOYEE_CODE", _
                Trim$(TxtIDcardNo.text)) = True Then
                MsgBox (gEmployeeCode)
                Call MessageBox("This ID Number is already existing for another  employee. Cannot enter duplicate number!Using By Employee Code:" & gEmployerCode & " ", OKOnly, Information, DefaultButton1, Me.Caption)
                sstInformationTab.Tab = 0
```

Comment: Are you talking about the call to MsgBox or MessageBox

Comment: Isn't there a typo: gEmployeeCode vs gEmployerCode?

Comment: MeassageBox is the  function that i have created by passing some arguments..Msgbox is just a vb function..I am just testing what gEmployeeCode returns me. @Rob

Comment: @Arvo  gEmployeeCode and gEmployerCode  are the fields of same table. i defined both like   : Public gEmployerCode As String
Public gEmployeeCode As String

Comment: You are not using gEmployeeCode anywhere in your function, so you are just returning True or False from your function. I can't see, how presented code is related to your question :(

Comment: What should i do then, suggest me what should i write in the function so that i can get employeeCode.. This returns me a simple msgbox written nothing in this. i need employee code in that..Help me out please @Arvo

Comment: I suggest to read employeecode from recordset and return it - or assign it to byref type function parameter. I hope you can understand, what every line in your function does, after all?

Comment: @Arvo  Thanks for your reply, I tried with ByRef type Function parameter.but it still giving me the same result..:(

Comment: Good, but I can't see, where you read employee code from recordset...

Comment: okay @Arvo Can we have a live chat if possible??

Comment: Live chat? Sorry, I have no consulting company here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arvo said, you need to make youre EmployeeCode variable ByRef, then assign it a value in your function Custom()

```
Public Function Custom(ByVal TableName As String, _
    **ByRef EmployeeCode As String**, ByVal FieldName As String, ByVal DataToCheck As String, _
    Optional ByVal CodeFieldName As String = Empty, Optional ByVal CodeFieldValue As String = Empty) As Boolean

Dim lstrSQL1 As String
Dim lrsTemp1 As ADODB.Recordset

    lstrSQL1 = " Select  " & FieldName & "  from  " & TableName & " Where ID_CARD_NO =" & DataToCheck & ""
    'MsgBox (lstrSQL1)

    If Len(Trim$(CodeFieldName)) <> 0 And Len(Trim$(CodeFieldValue)) <> 0 Then
       lstrSQL1 = lstrSQL1 & " AND " & CodeFieldName & " <> '" & CodeFieldValue & "'"
    End If

    Set lrsTemp1 = cObjDBConn.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL1)

    If lrsTemp1 Is Nothing Then
        Custom = False
    ElseIf Not (lrsTemp1.BOF And lrsTemp1.EOF) Then
        Custom = True
        **lrsTemp1.MoveFirst**
        **EmployeeCode = lrsTemp1.Fields("EMPLOYEE_CODE")**
    ElseIf lrsTemp1.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Custom = False
    Else
        Custom = False
    End If

    If lrsTemp1.State = adStateOpen Then lrsTemp1.Close
    Set lrsTemp1 = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrorHandle:
    Custom = False
End Function
```

The double asterisks are just to highlight the changes I made to your original code.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but its giving me Run time error on If lrsTemp1.State = adStateOpen Then lrsTemp1.Close